# Entropy and conditional probability given several variables

Tags: conditional-probability, entropy

Following 
[Calculating conditional entropy given two random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168316/calculating-conditional-entropy-given-two-random-variables)

I would like to figure out how to extend the entropy to several given variables:
For two variables:
$H(X|Y,Z) = -\sum p(x,y,z)log_{2}p(x|y,z)$
$H(X\mid Y,Z)=H(X,Y,Z)-H(Y,Z)=H(X,Y,Z)-H(Y\mid Z)-H(Z)$

Now if I have $H(X|Y,Z, A, B)$ I can write:
$H(X|Y,Z, A, B) = -\sum p(x,y,z, a, b)log_{2}p(x|y,z, a, b)$
$= -\sum p(x,y,z, a, b)log_{2}p(y\mid z, a, b)p(x|y,z, a, b)p(z\mid a, b)p(a\mid b)p(b)$

Can I develop this in a simpler way?

and:
$H(X\mid Y,Z,A,B)=H(X,Y,Z,A,B)-H(Y,Z, A, B)=H(X,Y,Z,A,B)-H(Y\mid Z,A,B)-H(Z\mid A,B)-H(A\mid B) - H(B)$

Am I right?

Thank you for your answers!
B.

Comment: log of product = sum of logs

Answer (score 0):

Entropy satisfies the following easily checked "chain rule": $H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y|X)$

So, one way to develop your identity is to treat $(Y,Z,A,B)$ as a new random variable, say $\Theta$. Then, we have $H(X|\Theta) = H(X,\Theta) - H(\Theta) = H(X,Y,Z,A,B) - H(Y,Z,A,B)$. Now one can expand $H(Y,Z,A,B)$ again using the chain rule to get the expression you have.

Comment: Hello Skoro,Thank you for your answer. So following your reasoning I could write: H(X|Y,Z,A,B) = (X,Y,Z,A,B) - H(Y,Z,A,B)-H(Z,A,B)-H(A,B)-H(B) is that right ?

Comment: Yup! All this boils down to, as Robert Israel says, the fact that log of product = sum of logs.

Comment: Great, thank to both of you. That will help :)

Comment: Hi again, I tried to develop the expression following what you said to obtain exactly H(X|Y,Z,A,B) = H(X,Y,Z,A,B) - H(Y,Z,A,B)-H(Z,A,B)-H(A,B)-H(B) but the different terms cancel and at the end I get only  H(X|Y,Z,A,B) = H(X,Y,Z,A,B) - H(Y,Z,A,B) only. Sorry to ask again but do you confirm that H(X|Y,Z,A,B) = H(X,Y,Z,A,B) - H(Y,Z,A,B)-H(Z,A,B)-H(A,B)-H(B) ? There is something I dont understand... Thank you. B.

Comment: @user2501025, you are missing the conditioning ("$|$") in your first expression, i.e., the _correct_ identity is $H(X|Y,Z,A,B) = H(X,Y,Z,A,B) - H(Y∣Z,A,B)−H(Z∣A,B)−H(A∣B)−H(B)$.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I could get expressions without conditioning :)